# Not able to use FormattableString

Tags: c#, .net-core, formattablestring

Reading [this interesting article](https://adrientorris.github.io/entity-framework-core/SQL-Injection-attacks-in-Entity-Framework-Core-2-0.html) about SQL injection prevention in EF Core, I found out that now an interpolated string may result in a `FormattableString`.

Running this test code in .NET Core 2.2:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var filter = "Mark'; DROP TABLE tbl; --";

    Console.WriteLine(FromSql("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE fld = '" + filter + "'"));
    Console.WriteLine(FromSql($"SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE fld = {filter}"));
    Console.WriteLine(FromSql(FormattableStringFactory.Create(
                                  "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE fld = {0}", filter)));
}

private static string FromSql(string sql) => sql;

private static string FromSql(FormattableString sql)
{   
    var formatArgs = sql.GetArguments();

    for (var paramIndex = 0; paramIndex < sql.ArgumentCount; ++paramIndex)
        formatArgs[paramIndex] = "@p" + paramIndex;

    return sql.ToString();
}
```

is not giving what I expected:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE fld = 'Mark'; DROP TABLE tbl; --'
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE fld = Mark'; DROP TABLE tbl; --
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE fld = @p0
```

The second print should output like the last one.

Try this is [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3UeFBS).

What am I missing?

Comment: I guess the answer is that a string literal starting with a `$` does not actually construct a string of type `FormattableString` - I guess the compiler hasn't caught up with the library.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError In the linked article, they use that exact syntax and it works. The called EF Core method is similar to what I wrote, you can see it here:https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/915d214351f6c691f7fe7563bf7f9d51274845b0/src/EFCore.Relational/Extensions/RelationalQueryableExtensions.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second call `Console.WriteLine(FromSql($"SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE fld = {filter}"));` looks to be going to the `FromSql(string sql)` overload instead of `FromSql(FormattableString sql)`.

Just remove the `FromSql(string sql)` method *(and the first call to it)*,
and it will go as expected; see the modified [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kh1MMk).

---

The compiler seems to translate
`var q = $"SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE fld = {filter}";` to a `string`.

```
 String q = $"SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE fld = {filter}";`
```

Because of the `string` type, a `String.Format` has taken place.
From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated):

> If an interpolated string has the type **string**, it's typically transformed into a **String.Format** method call .

Whereas explicitly specifying `FormattableString` as in

```
FormattableString q = $"SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE fld = {filter}";
```

a `FormattableStringFactory.Create` is being used.
From the  [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated):

> If an interpolated string has the type IFormattable or **FormattableString**, the compiler generates a call to the **FormattableStringFactory.Create** method.

Comment: Interesting, it seems that the other overload in the source code I linked in the comment above uses RawSqlString instead of string. This way probably the compiler can understand which overload to call.

Comment: Mystery solved, it's written on the `RawSqlString` doc page: "This type enables overload resolution between the regular and interpolated FromSql()" - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.rawsqlstring

Comment: Funny thing is that now they marked that method as obsolete and replaced it with two explicit implementations: FromSqlRaw and FromSqlInterpolated.